# How To Test A Unity Game On android emulator with a specific android version?

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-emulator

I made a game with unity 3d version 2019.1 and uploaded it on playstore , later i received reports that it was crashing on android 8.1 , after searching I downloaded unity 2021.1 and upgraded the project , When I try to test the game on the android emulator dowloaded with android studio , with android version 8.1 , I receive an error that the game is 64 bit and the emulator is 32 bit , then i tried using bluestack , but i didn't find any setting about the android version and the game didn't even work on it because the hardware requirements were not met.
So How can i test the game on android 8.1 since that i dont own a physical phone with this specific version ?